# POST value from dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have 2 dropdown the main and sub. I'm trying to POST a value of two dropdownlist but everytime I submit I get this in url `dyna.php?main=2&sub=2&submit=Submit` and nothing appears when I echo the post values. I want to post the value of two dropdown in same page because I'm going to make a query for the that values.

Here's my fullcode

dyna.php

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
 Drop1
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lists");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM main_list GROUP BY id ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
       $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id_no'].'">'.$row['value'].'</option>';
    }
    ?>

     <select id="main" name="main">
     <option selected=selected>Choose</option>
       <?php echo $option; ?>
     </select>
    <div id="sublist"></div>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#main').change(function(){
$.ajax({
url : 'secondlist.php',
data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
dataType:'html',
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
$('#sublist').html(data);
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
```

Secondlist.php

```
<?php
$out = $_POST['mainlist_id'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lists");
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
    select 
        a.id, a.value, a.id_no, b.id, b.category, b.value
    from
    (select *
    from main_list) a 
    left outer join
    (select *
    from sub_list) b 
    on a.id_no=b.category
    WHERE a.id_no='$out'
    ");
    $option1 = '';

    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $option1 .= '<option value = "'.$row['category'].'">'.$row['value'].'</option>';
    }

    $output = 'Drop2 ';
    $output .= '<select name="sub" id="sub"  onchange="run()">';
    $output .= '<option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose one</option>';
    $output .= $option1;
    $output .= '</select> ';
echo $output;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: 1st of all in ur action u r not echoing php_self, and as a note u can use empty string in action to point to same page action=""

Comment: Try: print_r($_POST) and print_r($_GET) in Secondlist.php. Maybe you're not using POST but GET...

Comment: data: $('form1').serialize(); // try commenting the POST and just alert the serialized value

Comment: ond if you want to use like that use data :{mainlist_id : $(this).find(':selected').val()}, \n instead of data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},

Comment: First of all Happy New Year, sorry for late response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dyna.php`
first add method in form.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
```

then  `<div id="sublist"></div>` replace this with following:

```
<select name="sub" id="sub"  onchange="run()">
 <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

and in `secondlist.php`

```
<?php
    $out = $_POST['mainlist_id'];
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "lists");
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("
    select 
        a.id, a.value, a.id_no, b.id, b.category, b.value
    from
    (select *
    from main_list) a 
    left outer join
    (select *
    from sub_list) b 
    on a.id_no=b.category
    WHERE a.id_no='$out'
    ");
    while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $row['category'];?>"><?php echo $row['value'];?></option>';
    <?php 
    }
?>
```

and in `dyna.php`
change this jquery line `$('#sublist').html(data);` to `$('#sub').html(data);`

and be aware of SQL injection.[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Happy New Year :), where should I echo the post values?

Comment: Thanks and same to you.which post value?

Comment: I got it, I get the Post values of two dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in .ready of jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'secondlist.php',
            data :{mainlist_id : $(this).val()},
            dataType:'html',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                $('#sublist').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: $(this).val() it`s a select not an imput box [textarea/input[type=text/password]  so it`s normal do display no data

Comment: @CatalinSterian what do u mean, i don't undertsatnd? and inside $('#main').change which is select, this.val will give the value of selected item of select(dropdown)

Comment: i suggested to use $(this).find(':selected').val(); just to be sure he gets the seected value ...

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the form using the button, you are using the default GET method when nothing is specified. GET appends the formdata as url encoded query string to your action URL.

To submit the data using HTTP POST, use the form attribute `method="post"`

If you want to add a file form field, add the parameter `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as well

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
</form>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
$('#form1').submit(
function(a){
alert($('#form1').serialize());
a.preventDefault();
})
})

</script>


<div>
    <form id="form1" name="form1">
    <select name="opton1">

    <option value="1"> option 11 </option>
    <option value="2"> option 12 </option>
    <option value="3"> option 13 </option>
    <option value="4"> option 14 </option>
    </select>   

    <select name="opton2">
    <option value="21"> option 21 </option>
    <option value="22"> option 22 </option>
    <option value="23"> option 23 </option>
    <option value="24"> option 24 </option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit">
    </form>

</div>
```

just a simple example